# Stickers not appearing XCode 13 - Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making a sticker pack in XCode 13 just using the regular template they have set up. I uploaded a set of stickers along with an app icon, but for some reason, the stickers don't show up. The app icon appears fine in imessages and you can click on it, but it just opens a blank space. It throws back at me this message:
Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this because you do not have enough icons loaded into the Message App Icon section? Have you made sure that your icons are not blank in this section? If you add more icons this error message may go away. Your app should build and you will see your stickers.